# Display consecutive number in table column

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display a consecutive number in my table column.

I am using a wordpress page template. Below you can see my example code:

```
<div id="comparison-table" style="display: block;">
<h2 id="matratzen-testsieger">Die besten Federkernmatratzen</h2>
<table class="comparison-table" style="max-width: 1050px;">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="row-name" data-name="name">
         <th> </th>
         <?php int i=0; //Here I am initializing the counter?>
         <?php if ( $posts->have_posts() ) { while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); global $post; ?>
         <td>
            <div class="product-title">
            <div class="ranking">
               <?php i++; echo i; ?>
               <div><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
         </td>
         <?php endwhile; } else { echo '<h4>' . __( 'Posts not found', 'shortcodes-ultimate' ) . '</h4>'; } ?>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row-mtester-rating" data-name="mtester-rating">
      <th> </th>
      <?php if ( $posts->have_posts() ) { while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); global $post; ?>
      <td>
      <span class="review-total-boxi"><?php the_field('wp_review_total'); ?> / 5.0</span>
      </td>
      <?php endwhile; } else { echo '<h4>' . __( 'Posts not found', 'shortcodes-ultimate' ) . '</h4>'; } ?>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I tried it with a simple counter `i`, which is incremented in the `while` loop and then `echoed`.

As an output I get nothing back.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: error reporting right now, should be throwing you an `undefined constant i` notice; **IF** `int i=0` - `i++; echo i;` is your *real* code.

Comment: Plus, `int i=0;` that is JS/C syntax, `int` needs to be referenced as `(int)` if you're going to be wanting to use that.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confused with another language. You're creating and calling variables without using `$` and in PHP you don't init variable with the type

```
<?php int i=0; ?>
```

should be

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
```

and

```
<?php i++; echo i; ?>
```

should be

```
<?php $i++; echo $i; ?>
```

etc

Comment: True, yet you missed a few more `i`'s ;-) and something else. Look again. (This, as per original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40366850/1).